# Nomeando subblocks de qualquer metablock com uma única classe?

Tags: java

Estou tentando fazer com que apenas uma classe seja necessária para nomear os subblocks de qualquer metablock que usar essa classe na hora do registro, ou seja, nomeá-los como se fossem valores de parâmetro, mas sem usar um.

Apesar de isso girar em torno de uma API (Minecraft Forge), acho que o problema é mais de Java, então faço aqui uma breve explicação de como funciona o que tenho intenção de fazer.

Um metablock é composto de subblocks, que são variações do mesmo bloco (como por exemplo, o mesmo bloco, mas que só muda a textura e o nome). Cada subblock precisa de um nome para o identificar. Esses nomes são listados na classe `ExemploItemBlock` em uma `String[]`, e depois são nomeados no formato `nomeDoMetablock.nomeDoSubBlock` (ex.: `ExemploMetablock.azul`, `ExemploMetablock.verde`, etc.), com

```
// Classe ExemploItemBlock

public static final String[] SUBNAMES = new String[] {"azul", "verde", "amarelo"};

@Override
public String getUnlocalizedName(ItemStack itemStack) 
{
    int i = itemStack.getItemDamage();
    return getUnlocalizedName() + "." + SUBNAMES[i];
}
```

Depois o metablock `ExemploMetaBlock` é instanciado e registrado com

```
// Classe onde são feitos os registros   

public static Block ExemploMetaBlock = new ExemploMetaBlock(); 

GameRegistry.registerBlock(ExemploMetaBlock, ExemploItemBlock.class, "ExemploMetaBlock");
```

Após isso, tudo funciona sem problemas, porém eu teria que criar uma classe ItemBlock para cada metablock novo que eu quiser fazer, e não acho isso muito prático ou apropriado, achando melhor criar uma única classe para ser usada por qualquer metablock futuro.

Como é possível perceber, o segundo parâmetro do método `GameRegistry.registerBlock()` (que é um método da API) requer um valor do tipo `Class`. E é aí que está o problema: como vou tornar a classe `ExemploItemBlock` dinâmica sem usar instâncias?

Eu até tentei adicionar um parâmetro String[] no construtor da `ExemploItemBlock` e usar uma instância com os nomes no lugar do nome da classe, mas como era de esperar, acusou incompatibilidade de tipos, pois é apenas `Class` o tipo aceito.

Eu procurei por toda parte um jeito de fazer isso, mas só encontrei dois jeitos:

**1.** criar uma classe ItemBlock para cada novo metablock;
**2.** trocar `SUBNAMES[i]` no `getUnlocalizedName()` por `i` ou `itemStack.getItemDamage()` nomeando assim os subblocks por números ao invés de nomes (ex.: `ExemploMetaBlock.0`, `ExemploMetaBlock.1`, etc.), sem precisar usar o String[] nem nada e se tornando uma classe universal. Porém esse jeito também é bem antiprático, porque depois dificulta bastante na hora de identificar qual subblock é qual.

Então minha pergunta é: há algum jeito de se conseguir uma classe ItemBlock universal, mas nomear os subblocks por nomes (palavras)?

Conteúdo das classes: [ExemploMetaBlock](http://pastebin.com/SFFwuS64), [ExemploItemBlock](http://pastebin.com/eftu2uKk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acabei encontrando a solução no próprio Forge, como pode ser acompanhado [aqui](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/modification-development/2608361-naming-subblocks-from-any-metablock-using-one).

Mas pelo bem da informação, vou dar uma explicada sobre a solução.

---

Não sabia, mas o método `GameRegistry.registerBlock()` também aceita um quarto parâmetro, do tipo `Object[]`. Então basta colocar a lista com os nomes dentro do `Object[]`, apenas iniciar a variável `String[]` da `ExemploMetablock`, e passar os valores definidos no parâmetro Object[] para a variável `String[]`. Ficando assim:

```
public static String[] SUBNAMES;
private IIcon[] icon;

public ExemploMetaBlock(Material material, String name, CreativeTabs tab, String[] subnames)
{
    super(material, name, tab);
    SUBNAMES = subnames;
}
```

E ao invés de usar a classe `ExemploItemBlock`, uma classe criada separada, no parâmetro `Class`, recomendo que use no lugar uma classe que já existe no próprio código do Minecraft e que faz praticamente a mesma coisa que o `ExemploItemBlock`, que é a classe `ItemMultiTexture` (isso caso não tenha nada a mais que não tenha na `ItemMultiTexture`). Ficando o registro assim:

```
public static final String[] SubNames = new String[] {"azul", "verde", "amarelo", "vermelho"}; 
public static Block ExemploMetablock = new ExemploMetablock(Material.rock, "ExemploMetablock", Tabs.ExemploModTab, SubNames); 

GameRegistry.registerBlock(ExemploMetablock, ItemMultiTexture.class, "ExemploMetablock", new Object[]{SubNames});
```

Porém, isso não compilará. Ocorrerá o erro `NoSuchMethodException` na linha do registro (`GameRegistry.registerBlock` ....).

O construtor da classe `ItemMultiTexture` pega os valores definidos nos parâmetros do método `registerBlock()` que correspondem com os tipos dos parâmetros de seu construtor, que são `Block, Block, String[]`.

Foi informado um `String[]`? Sim. Foi informado um `Block`? Sim. Foi informado um segundo `Block`? Não. "Não há tal método", não há um construtor da `ItemMultiTexture` com parâmetros `Block, String[]`.

Isso acontece porque, como foi dito, o construtor da classe `ItemMultiTexture` requer dois valores `Block`.

Para resolver isso, simplesmente crie uma nova classe (ou substitua a `ExemploItemBlock`) estendendo `ItemMultiTexture` e que `super` os dois `Block`s no parâmetro. Ficando assim:

```
public class ItemMultiTextureHelper extends ItemMultiTexture
{
    public ItemMultiTextureHelper(Block block, String[] names)
    {
        super(block, block, names);
    }
}
```

E o `registerBlock()` assim:

```
GameRegistry.registerBlock(ExemploMetablock, ItemMultiTextureHelper.class, "ExemploMetablock", new Object[]{SubNames});
```

E uma última coisa, mas não menos importante: **remova** o modificador `static` do `SUBNAMES`, caso contrário isso causará a maior bagunça nos metablocks futuros, como por exemplo, todos os sub-blocks dos metablocks sendo nomeados com os nomes dos do primeiro metablock criado, sub-blocks repetidos, etc. (Eu passei por esses problemas agora mesmo, e corrigi removendo o `static`.) Então o correto é, na verdade, assim:

```
public String[] SUBNAMES;
```